# Adding comma or semi_colon after 5 characters in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work with a txt file with no separators. I want to add a comma or semi-colon after the 5 first characters but I'm a bit rusty.
Txt file (600 lines) looks like this :

```
DEU02 Allemagne
ANDMA Andorre 
AGOUT Angola 
JAMDC Anguilla (Île)
```

The output I'm looking for is :

```
DEU02; Allemagne
ANDMA; Andorre 
AGOUT; Angola 
JAMDC; Anguilla (Île)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice values by `str` accessor and add `;`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str[:5] + ';' + df['col'].str[5:]
print (df)
                     col
0       DEU02; Allemagne
1         ANDMA; Andorre
2          AGOUT; Angola
3  JAMDC; Anguilla (Île)
```

Another idea is create 2 columns with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['code','name']] = df['col'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
                    col   code            name
0       DEU02 Allemagne  DEU02       Allemagne
1         ANDMA Andorre  ANDMA         Andorre
2          AGOUT Angola  AGOUT          Angola
3  JAMDC Anguilla (Île)  JAMDC  Anguilla (Île)
```

Comment: I was so close ><
df["Code"] = df["Code"].astype(str)[:5] + ';' + df["Code"].astype(str)[5:]

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need pandas:

```
with open('in.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for l in f:
        f_out.write(l[:5]+';'+l[5:])
```

Else, you can leverage [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
# read with one column for the first 5 characters
# one for the rest, then export with ";" as delimiter
(pd.read_csv('in.txt', sep=r'(?<=^\S{5})', header=None)
   .to_csv('out.txt', sep=';', index=False, header=None)
)
```

Or:

```
# read all file with one column, then replace and export
(pd.read_csv('in.txt', sep='--none--', header=None)
   [0].str.replace(r' ', '; ', n=1, regex=False)
   .to_csv('out.txt', header=None, index=False)
)
```

*Or for an exact match of 5 characters: `replace(r'(?<=^.{5})', ';', regex=True)`.*

Output file (`out.txt`):

```
DEU02; Allemagne
ANDMA; Andorre
AGOUT; Angola
JAMDC; Anguilla (Île)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in a dataframe, you could also use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the character position 5 from the beginning of the string (using a regex lookbehind) with a `;`:

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(?<=^.{5})', ';', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0         DEU02; Allemagne
1           ANDMA; Andorre
2            AGOUT; Angola
3    JAMDC; Anguilla (Île)
```

Comment: I had to fix mine, initially used `^(?<=.{5})` instead of `(?<=^.{5})`, took me 2 minutes to realize ;)

Comment: I didn't notice that in your answer? It couldn't match as it would require the beginning of string to be preceded by 5 characters - pretty tricky in our universe :)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't focused, it's one of those stupid mistakes :D

Comment: We all make them...

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df['col'].str.replace(r'^(.{5})', r'\1;', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0         DEU02; Allemagne
1           ANDMA; Andorre
2            AGOUT; Angola
3    JAMDC; Anguilla (Île)
Name: col, dtype: object
```